# WIFI problems and how to activate TCP Westwood

Tags: tcp, wifi, freeze

We have problems when using a device on windows compact framework 2.0 (windows mobile) and a server with IIS (7) on windows server 2008 R2. We are on WIFI.

We encounter many problems of latency and freezing. Our app is pretty simple. It just send a very small request (a string of 10 chars) to the server which will respond with a string of the same length. There is a request from the device to the server every 3 or 4 seconds.

It works well for some times and suddenly it freeze. It does that with other clients environment : so the only things which vary is the network itself (not the device or the server they both were tested separately and together and they perform well on a wired network).

We are using TCP and we read that it does not work so well on WIFI where the packet loss are not always due to the same reason when on a wired network (congestion).

**Does somebody had freezing problems like us on TCP over WIFI ? Do you think we pointed out the same problem as you (TCP over WIFI) ?**

We would like to change the protocol used. The first thing we would like to try is TCP Westwood.

**Is TCP Westwood not offered on windows server and windows mobile ? If yes, how do you activate it ?**.

Our last solution is to build our own server and protocol using UDP. But it's a hard work.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I can't answer your actual questions (unfortunately, your question is one of the few places people mention microsoft and TCP westwood in the first couple of pages on google).  Do have to ask, if you're still working this, did you try Wireshark?  For your application protocol (sending 10 bytes ever 3 seconds), this really shouldn't be the issue you're seeing.  You might want to post your code (if it's short enough) to see if someone can point out some edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the TCP_NODELAY socket option as your sending small chunks less than 1500. This will improve performance in a lossy network.